# Running Tests in CLion using CMake's CTest

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, clion, ctest

I have a C++ project using CMake. The project is built on CentOS machine. I have configured CLion to build remotely from MacOS. I have unit tests for the project and I am trying to run them from CLion. I can run the tests from CentOS machine using CTest like below

```
ctest -r utCppProject -v
```

CLion tries to run the executable directly with gtest flags like below

```
./utCppProject --gtest_filter=* --gtest_color=no
Process finished with exit code 0
```

No tests are actually run.

How can I configure CLion to be able to use CTest for running unit tests?

Here is my CMakeLists.txt for the unit test project

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include(../../cmake-dependencies/Boost.cmake)
include(../../cmake-dependencies/GoogleTest.cmake)

set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../build")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)


include_directories(${GOOGLE_TEST_DIR}/googletest/include)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include)


set(TARGET utCppProject)

add_executable (
   ${TARGET}
   utCppProject.cpp
)

target_link_libraries (
    ${TARGET}
    CppProject
    gtest
    boost_system
    pthread
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fPIC -DPIC -Wall -Werror -std=c++0x")

set(TEST_OUTPUT "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test_results/${TARGET}.xml")
add_test(${TARGET} ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${TARGET})
set_tests_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES
  ENVIRONMENT 
  "UT_FOLDER_PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR};GTEST_OUTPUT=xml:${TEST_OUTPUT}")
```

Comment: @adsum am I right that you create GTest run configuration to run CTest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily configure CLion to use CTest. Simply duplicate the default configuration for the test target and configure it to use the CTest executable and set the working directory to the build directory:
[image]

In detail:

- Executable > Select other... > Find and select ctest (for me it is `/usr/bin/ctest`, on UNIX-like systems you can use `which ctest` to find it)
- Set program arguments - `-j` sets the amount of threads to use, then the name of the executable to test, and `--output-on-failure` to get the test output when something went wrong - you could simply set it to `-r utCppProject -v`
- Set working directory to `cmake-build-debug` under the project dir, the default build directory for CLion

Answer (score 3):

Since CLion 2020.3 EAP CTest is [supported from the box](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/09/clion-ctest-support/).

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no CTest support in CLion.

[The feature request is here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-905).

Comment: Since CLion 2020.3 EAP it is. (CPP-905 is updated accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

Since version CLion 2020.3 the CTest is [supported from the box for CMake 3.14 and above](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/12/clion-2020-3-debug-misra-qt/).